# React Native conditionally setting state

Tags: react-native

I have an array of "favorite" listings per user. I want to set a state variable depending on if it is rendering a favorite item or a regular (non-favorite) item. This is a little heart icon that is either filled or unfilled. It is incorrectly setting the state on first render. Correctly sets it after refresh.. I'm doing something wrong and have tried many things to no avail so if someone could just look at this code and tell me if you see any glaring flaws. If not then I will look elsewhere for the problem.

Behavior when app loads: I am doing console.log just after the state is set to show whether it's a favorite or not, and the contents of the favorite state variable (an image url, but in the console it shows it as either 21 for non-fav, or 22 for a fav). I can see that it is correctly pulling the array of favorites, and correctly identifying those that are and are not favorited (1 means its a favorite). It is however not setting the state variable correctly. Furthermore, it IS setting it correctly for only *some* of the listings. Currently I have all listings marked as a favorite, and it only messes up the first 10. After that they all set right. MORE bizarre, is upon refreshing the screen, it correctly sets all of them.

MainHeader.js (pulling data from db, setting initial array of favorite listings, and passing it to the messagesScreen component)

```
const [favsArray, setFavsArray] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    lookupUser()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          let favs = childSnapshot.child("favorites").val();
          setFavsArray(favs);
        })
      }         
    })
    .catch((error) => {console.error('Error:', error)});
  }, []);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={require("../assets/newheader4.png")}
        />
      </View>
      <Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: "blue",
          inactiveTintColor: "black",
          style: {},
          tabStyle: {
            width: "auto",
            backgroundColor: "#e0d5f3",
            borderTopWidth: 3,
            borderBottomWidth: 3,
            borderRightColor: "gray",
          },
          labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
          scrollEnabled: true,
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="All Deals" children={()=><MessagesScreen favsArray={favsArray} setFavsArray={setFavsArray}/>} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

MessagesScreen, receives favsArray and renders a FlatList with component Card which it feeds favsArray to.

```
<FlatList
          data={messagesShow}
          keyExtractor={(messagesShow) => messagesShow.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Card
              price={item.currentPrice}
              title={item.title}
              image={item.image}
              posted={item.postedDate}
              discAmount={item.discountAmount}
              discType={item.discType}
              expiration={item.expiration}
              promoCode={item.promoCode}
              affLink={item.amzLink}
              indexStore={item.indexStore}
              store={item.store}
              favsArray = {favsArray}
            />
          )}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.messagesList}
          refreshing={refreshing}
          onRefresh={() =>
            db.ref('deals').once('value', (snapshot) =>{
              let testData = [];
              snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
              //  if (child.val().hasOwnProperty('title')){
                  testData.push({
                    id: child.key,
                    title: child.val().hasOwnProperty('title') ? child.val().title : 'NA',
                    currentPrice: child.val().price,
                    discountAmount: child.val().discAmt,
                    discType: child.val().discType,
                    promoCode: child.val().promoCode,
                    expiration: child.val().expDate,
                    postedDate: child.val().postDate,
                    image: { uri: child.val().imageLink}, 
                    amzLink: child.val().affLink,
                    category: child.val().category,
                    indexStore: child.val().indexStore,
                    store: child.val().store
                  })
            //  }
                checkMessages(testData);
              }) 
            })
            .then()
            .catch((error) => {console.error('Error:', error)})
          }
        />
```

Card component, this is in a FlatList where favsArray is passed as a prop (correctly verified by console), along with the individual listing data. If it finds the listing in the fav array, it should set to HeartFilled (1), if not set to HeartEmpty (0).

```
  let test = [];
  test = favsArray.split(',');
  let isFav = 0;
  let found = test.find(function (element) { 
    return element == indexStore; 
  }); 
  if (found != undefined){
    isFav = 1;
  }

  const [heartFilled, setHeartFilled] = useState( isFav == 1 ? require('../assets/heartFilled.png') : require('../assets/heartEmpty.png'));
  console.log(isFav + ' ' + heartFilled);
```

Looking at my console, you can see it correctly shows each listing as a favorite, but for the first 10 listings it sets the state to the wrong image (21, shown in red). These should all be 22.

[image: console output]

Comment: I was able to accomplish what I needed by making a brand new component just for the heart image to display as favorited or not, and putting a useEffect in with an isRendered test before setting state. For some reason my brain is really struggling to wrap around the concept of async functions and how to work them into the program flow.